# Chrome Not Saving Passwords on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, passwords

I recently was forced to destroy everything in the ~/Library/Keychains folder on my Mac (we're using Active Directory users and I've always had keychain troubles when it's time to change the password). I've done this plenty of times before.

However this time, Chrome is no longer saving passwords at all. It still prompts me if I want to save them and occasionally autofills a name (though I suspect that's Mac OS rather than Chrome).

I've already checked and both boxes under "Passwords and Forms" are checked in settings. There are no sites listed under "Manage Passwords." I've also checked to make sure both the Local Items and Login Items keychains are unlocked in Keychain Access.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had the same issue when my IT folks at work nuked my keychain. I uninstalled and installed chrome following the steps [here](http://crunchify.com/how-to-purge-all-your-google-chrome-user-data-on-mac-os-x/).

> 1. Go to `~/<username>/Library` folder.
> 2. Delete Google folder from `~/Library/Application Support`.
> 3. Delete below folders from `~/Library/Caches`
>      [image]
> 4. Delete `~/Library/Google` folder
>
> Make sure you’ve shut down Chrome while performing this action and
>   then either move the folder to the trash or rename it to something
>   like backup. Chrome and then start Chrome up again.
>
> This will fresh start your Google Chrome.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you kindly! (I seriously should have thought of this myself. It's basic program reset 101 for Mac)

Comment: By these process, you will lost all stored data on your browser, be careful and save them before you removed them

Comment: Deleting the Google Drive folders is not necessary.

Comment: @Fa.Shapouri which is why you sign into Chrome to save it to the cloud and then import back....you might need another computer though.

Comment: You don't have to delete everything, you only need to quit Chrome completely, then delete "Login Data" and "Login Data-journal" from ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile X/ . If you have a lot of profiles you can do this with a one liner: find ~/Library/"Application Support"/Google/Chrome/ -type f -name "Login Data*" -delete

Comment: @AndyFraley, deleting those two sub-folders worked.  Consider making a separate answer so we can upvote it as this answer, while correct, is overkill.

Answer (score 2):

An important addition to [this comprehensive answer](https://superuser.com/a/1013071/567048). This will only work if you sign out of your Google account in Chrome. I tried this method several times and it wasn't until I signed out of Chrome, then deleted all the cached items and the Google folder in the Library folder that my passwords were restored.

Also, another tip (as osx has been updated).
To view the Library folder, when in
the User folder click on -> Show View Options -> There is a check box for Show Library Folder

You can also choose to show this as a default setting if required.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue after IT nuked my Keychains. I did not need to uninstall Chrome or delete folders manually. A variation of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1092874/129827) seems to work reliably.

Essentially, it seems that it is sufficient to nuke the specific user profile, rather than the entire Chrome installation. BTW, chrome://version/ reports 59.

Comment: Still works, in Chrome 65.

Answer (score -2):

I also had to delete my Mac keychain, and then Google Chrome would ask to save passwords but they would be gone every time I restarted Chrome- using OSX El Capitan... The above didn't work for me, but what DID work for me- go to Chrome-->Settings-->Advanced Settings-->Click on "Reset Settings". Restart Chrome, and- they saved!

Comment: Can down-voters PLEASE comment why they down-vote if it is not immediately obvious.  I don't think this answer is necessarily wrong so I'd like to know why.

Comment: It didn't work.  I had to not only use Gopi's answer above, but I also had to go into Keychain Access and delete any Google related application passwords as well.